# Box2D: Triangle causing "Polygon is degenerate"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, box2d

I am currently porting a small game engine to **Linux Ubuntu 14.04.4**. Everything works great, but I have encountered a problem with [Box2D](http://box2d.org). I use [Poly2Tri](https://github.com/greenm01/poly2tri) to triangulate my shapes. This library returns counter-clockwise triangles, which I then create [Box2D fixtures](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972) with.

Some triangles work, however at least one does not, this one for example:

```
P1: (-0.135156, -0.042188)
P2: (-0.136719, -0.050000)
P3: (-0.131250, -0.053125)
```

As you can see, this triangle is counter-clockwise. When Box2D attempts to create a shape with these vertices using `polygonShape->Set()`, I get a **Polygon is degenerate** assert:

```
/build/buildd/box2d-2.3.0+ds/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp:158: void b2PolygonShape::Set(const b2Vec2*, int32): Assertion `false' failed.
```

I was wondering why would I get this? After doing some research, I have found that polygons have to be counter-clockwise and not too tiny (coords have to be greater than 0.00001 or something), but my triangle **respects both constraints**. Also, **it worked fine on Windows!**

It is also interesting to note that it seems this assert can be thrown if Box2D's convex hull algorithm breaks on the polygon (or so I've heard).

Box2D versions:

- On Ubuntu: 2.3.0+ds-2
- On Windows: 2.3.0

Comment: If you have the box2d source code, have a look at Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp and see if you can find out what it's actually checking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the source that I've found](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/mvsim/html/b2PolygonShape_8cpp_source.html#l00120), `b2PolygonShape::Set()` is gluing together the vertices that are close to each other. Close means that the square distance is less than half of `b2_linearSlop` which is defined by default to [0.005f](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/mvsim/html/b2Settings_8h.html#a57268ade379c5c3373d0ff558b0350cf).

Which means the distance is less than `sqrt(0.005f / 2)`, that is `0.05`. This is definitely your case, and you may want to redefine `b2_linearSlop` to something smaller, or scale up the coordinates of the points.

Note: The math for the vertex gluing varies from one Box2D version to another, but making sure vertices are farther than `0.05f` seems safe.

Comment: Ouh! Yes, I modifying my code to filter out more points. However, my Box2D version has this:

`if (b2DistanceSquared(v, ps[j]) < ((0.5f * b2_linearSlop) * (0.5f * b2_linearSlop)))`

Comment: Doesn't that make it fail if the distance is less than `0.0025`?

Comment: @fordcars and what is the value of `b2_linearSlop` in your Box2D?

Comment: Also, you seem to be using Box2D 2.3.0, and here's the [the source for this version](https://box2d.googlecode.com/svn/tags/v2.3.0/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp) - the code is the same. Are you sure you are looking into the right file & the right function?

Comment: 0.005 :) I've added the filtering and my code works now

Comment: Check out https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/master/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp#L141 I think it is this version I got from Ubuntu repositories

Comment: I accepted the answer and proposed an edit saying that the distance varies in different Box2D versions, I don't even know which math I have.